# How can I see the browser log messages when running a selenium webdriverjs test

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, console.log

Is there a way to see the browser log messages (e.g. console.log) that a selenium webdriverjs test might generate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way I understand it you want to see the messages produced by the system under test? Try this:

```
    var logBrowserMessages = function(logEntries, driver, logging, cb) {
        return driver.manage().logs().get(logging.Type.BROWSER).then(function(entries) {
            entries.forEach(function(entry) {
                logEntries = logEntries + entry.level.name + ': ' + entry.message + '\n';
            });
            logEntries = logEntries + "\n";
            console.log('final entries:' + logEntries);
            return cb();
        });
    };
```

You will also need to require:

```
    var logging = require('selenium-webdriver').logging;
```

And set up the driver with logging preferances:

```
    var prefs = new logging.Preferences();
    prefs.setLevel(logging.Type.BROWSER, logging.Level.ALL);
    driver = new webdriver.Builder()
        .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome())
        .setLoggingPrefs(prefs)
        .build();
```

Then you can use logBrowserMessages:

```
    var doStuff = function(driver, logging) {
        return logBrowserMessages('', driver, logging, function() {
                //Do stuff
            });
        });
    };
```

Comment: Some additional info. According to webdriver standard if you will read logs twice the second reading operation will return only logs created after the first log reading operation (if any). Some webdrivers follow this rule (e.g. chromedriver), some - do not (e.g. phantomjs).

Comment: Is it possible to get the logs of a custom fragment? I tried your first snippet after my `driver.get("localhost:8080#htmlElementAction")` and empty entries are obtained. Thanks